# convert method to wait until query finishes

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, async-await, task, entity-framework-6.1

I am loading some data from database using query below. Can I use this method to await until this query finishes using await-async?

```
public static void LoadData()
        {
            using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities())
            {
                List<Employee> Employees = (from d in entities.Employees
                                            where d.Id > 100
                                            select new Employee
                                            {
                                                Name = d.LastName + ", " + d.FirstName
                                                DoB = d.dob
                                            }).ToList();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use this method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx;

```
public static async void LoadData()
    {
        using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities())
        {
            List<Employee> Employees = await (from d in entities.Employees
                                        where d.Id > 100
                                        select new Employee
                                        {
                                            Name = d.LastName + ", " + d.FirstName
                                            DoB = d.dob
                                        }).AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

If MyEntities is DbContext you can use

```
List<Employee> Employees = 
                   await entities.Set<Employee>()
                       .Where(d => d.Id > 100)
                       .Select(
                        d =>
                        new Employee
                        {
                            Name = d.LastName + ", " + d.FirstName,
                            DoB = d.dob
                        }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I am using EF6, however, I don't get ToListAsync as an option in intellicense. Include compilation error if include it anyways. What version of System.Data.Entity should I have? I have 4.0.0.0 for it. I am using .NET-4 and have nuget package for await async library

Comment: @johnsmith I edited answer. entities.Employees is DbSet?

Comment: yes it a DbSet but with AsQueryable, I still get same compilation issues when using ToListAsync

Comment: @johnsmith you have two new in Question. Whats compilation error?

Comment: sorry that was a typo, fixed. Error is 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListSync' and no extension method 'ToListSync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' could be found

Comment: @johnsmith tried the second option in my answer? Try it without select, disappears mistake?

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework has a `ToListAsync` method as of EF 6.0 that returns a `Task<List<T>>`, allowing you to `await` it.